# certain headers arent being found, even though I've included them. Aside from using quotes, how can I fix this?

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors

Ive downloaded the SDL2 library using `brew install SDL2` but when I am trying to compile melonDS for Mac, I keep banging my head against the wall of the annoying error of

```
bash-3.2$ make
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/bigman/melonDS/build
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/melonDS.dir/src/libui_sdl/main.cpp.o
/Users/bigman/melonDS/src/libui_sdl/main.cpp:24:10: fatal error: 
      'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/melonDS.dir/src/libui_sdl/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/melonDS.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
bash-3.2$
```

I've uninstalled, reinstalled, tried to use compiler flags in the makefile (which did't work because the project uses cmake) but to no avail. Any other reccomendations would be great.

Comment: You need to tell your build system where to find the library. CMake's `target_include_directories()` should fit the bill.

Comment: Re: "Aside from using quotes, how can I fix this?" -- in other words, aside from doing it right, how can I fix this. Angle brackets are for **standard headers**. Quotes are for everything else.

Comment: @JesperJuhl do you know what file that would be in? melonDS is open-source.

Comment: @PeteBecker yeah, i know the difference. i meant besides saying that when it asks for SDL.h having to do "/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/version/include/sdl.h" because i run into some big errors and its way too much of an overhaul to do that

Comment: @JesperJuhl in the project's CMakeLists in the `target_include_directories()` there is a ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} but that doesn't seem to be a variable on my system or in the makefile. would you assume replacing it with `/⁨usr⁩/local/Cellar⁩/sdl2⁩/2.0.9_1⁩/include⁩` would work?

Comment: @JesperJuhl so i did do that, i replaced the variables with the absolute paths, and now i'm getting an error for glib which isn't having the same easiness to deal with. i tired replacing it with both `/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.60.1/include/glib-2.0/` and `/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.60.1/include/` but neither worked.

on top of this i'm also getting a error that says https://pastebin.com/wbRa0kEJ